# How to filter JavaScript object based on property condition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a d3 visualization to create a sunburst. I am also adding a functionality to search for a particular arc  so that the sunburst displays arcs with only the searched label. If the initial object is:

```
{
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "color": "red",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "B",
                    "color": "red"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "C",
            "color": "red",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "D",
                    "color": "red"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "E",
            "color": "red",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "B",
                    "color": "red"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to filter this such that it returns the whole hierarchy which contains the searched name anywhere in the hierarchy. Below is a sample output required when searched for "name":"B"

```
{
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "color": "red",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "B",
                    "color": "red"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "E",
            "color": "red",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "B",
                    "color": "red"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please tell me if anything else might be needed. Thank you.

Code snippet of how I tried to filter.

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
           .data(partition.nodes(root))
           .enter()
           .append("path")
           .filter(function(d){ 
               return (d.name=="B");
           })
           .attr("d", arc)
           .style("fill", function(d) {
               console.log(d.name);
               return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); 
           })
```

This returns only "name":"B" arc and not the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the .filter() way to work for you, you will have to flatten your JSON data apply a filter and then unflatten it. You can check out flattening and unflattening if you are interested.
I personally prefer the depth-first-search (or bfs also works) and pruning where required approach. Lets assume your json data is present in mydata javascript var:

```
d3.json("jsonData.json",function(error,jsonData){
  if(error)
    return console.warn(error);
  var mydata = jsonData;
  dfs(mydata,'B');
});
```

Now your dfs() function will look something like this:

```
function dfs(data,label){
  if(!('children' in data))
    return data.name==label;
  for(var i=0;i<data.children.length;++i)
    if(dfs(data.children[i],label)==flase)
      data.children.splice(i--,1);
  return data.children.length > 0 || data.name==label;
}
```

What is happening here is that we are doing a depth-first search of the JSON data. The first IF condition checks if we are at the leaf node level and returns false if the 'name' property is anything but 'B'. Next we traverse all children of the current node, call dfs() for each child and prune that child if it returns false. At the end we return false if all children of current node have been pruned and if the 'name' property of current node is not 'B' (the condition that the non-leaf node also has to be pruned from the hierarchy). Hope this helps. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: I've tried implementing this. Thank you for the suggestion. However, I encountered an error on trying to implement the same. The link for jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Claw_22/vw611nx8/2/. On exploring I found that the input should be in array format for the splice function. I am now looking on how I can do this conversion.

Comment: oops! That line should be data.children.splice(i,1). We are trying to delete one of the children. Children is an array and hence splice should work. I'll edit my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: Tested after the change. It's working on my end and hierarchy is maintained after required deletions. Let me know if it works for you as well. Cheers!

Comment: Working like a charm. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I was trying with different combinations, however one gave me a wrong result. jsfiddle.net/Claw_22/vw611nx8/4. I've looked in the console and observed that after eliminating the first child, it indices the second child as 0 and skips it as for loop i has incremented to 1. This is what I am expecting. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Nice catch! That is exactly what is happening. A simple solution would be to decrement 'i' whenever a deletion happens, so as not to skip checking the immediately next child. Answer edited again to reflect the change.

Comment: Also, I have made the function more generic by adding the label being checked against as an input parameter. You need not change the hard-coded value each time you want to check against a new label. http://jsfiddle.net/vw611nx8/5/

Comment: I needed the filters on the leaf nodes and hence was able to use the solution without any problem. On trying it out more I observed that, the function doesn't return the complete hierarchy when the search string matches a property higher than the leaf node. I was able to get it working for one level higher http://jsfiddle.net/Claw_22/vw611nx8/7/. Can you please share your thoughts on generalizing this across the hierarchy.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand you properly. In the above jsfiddle, do you want the node with name 'G' to be removed? Or is it something else. If it's the former, the code in the answer (unchanged) should still work. If it's the latter, can you tell me which nodes should be pruned so I can get some clarity and look into necessary changes.

Comment: When I try searching for a name lets say 'B'. It currently gives output till the next child node ( and prunes 'G') . Whereas I would like the whole hierarchy as the output. So if the label is found at any depth in the hierarchy the whole hierarchy is returned.

Comment: Oh okay. As I understand you want to retain full branches in the hierarchy as long as one of the nodes in that branch has a matching label. This can be achieved very easily by simple not traversing further down a particular branch once you get a node with matching label. Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/vw611nx8/9/. I haven't changed the answer this time, just the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks again!! I'm slowly learning on doing these things on my own. I've started working on this recently, so thanks for all the help.

Comment: Always glad to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that you want to color the searching node and its parent in sunburst.

To do this i have made a function which recursively colors a node's parent like this:

```
function colorGraph(node){

    var sel = svg.selectAll("path").filter(function (d) {
        return (node==d);
    });
    sel.style("opacity", 1);
    //if parent present change its opacity
    if(node.parent){
        colorGraph(node.parent)
    }
}
```

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/m39qzqLc/2/)

Comment: Thank you for providing an alternative. However I am looking mainly to subset the json so that I can recreate the sunburst with the applied filter. The leaf nodes currently have many duplicates in different hierarchies. Hence, the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pre-filter, rather than doing it within the D3 pipeline.

Define a filter function we will call `hasName` which checks if a particular object has the desired name, or, recursively, if any of its children have it:

```
// Does the object contain a specified name, however many levels down?
function hasName(obj, name) {
  return function _hasName(o) {
    return o.name === name || (o.children || []).some(_hasName);
  }(obj);

}
```

Now filter:

```
data.children = data.children.filter(function(child) { return hasName(child, 'B'); });
```

Comment: This is a really elegant solution. Thanks